# Subsetting string vector by word count in one line

Tags: r, string, subset, stringr, sapply

I have a vector of strings

```
rownames
[1] "multifarmacias descuento" "multifarmacias"           "multifarmacias"
```

My goal is to subset `rownames` in one line by strings that only contain one word-  the output would be

```
[1] "multifarmacias"           "multifarmacias"
```

I have tried the following but it throws an error:

```
rownames[which(sapply(strsplit(rownames, " "),length)) == 1]

Error in which(sapply(strsplit(rownames, " "), length)) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Is there an elegant solution to subsetting a string vector by length of words the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
rownames[str_count(rownames, "\\w+") == 1]
#[1] "multifarmacias" "multifarmacias"
```

---

If we use `strsplit` with `lengths` (from `base R`) would be more efficient

```
rownames[lengths(strsplit(rownames, "\\s+")) == 1]
#[1] "multifarmacias" "multifarmacias"
```

---

The error in OP's post is based on the wrong placement of `)`, It should be after the `==1` because `which` is applied directly on a vector of lengths i.e.

```
 which(c(2, 1, 1))
```

> Error in which(c(2, 1, 1)) : argument to 'which' is not logical

#### data

```
rownames <- c("multifarmacias descuento", "multifarmacias", "multifarmacias")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` solution would be:

```
#Data
x <- c("multifarmacias descuento", "multifarmacias", "multifarmacias")

#Code
x[which(lapply(strsplit(x,split = ' '),length)==1)]
```

Output:

```
[1] "multifarmacias" "multifarmacias"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `grep`

```
grep("\\s",rownames,invert = TRUE,value = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> grep("\\s",rownames,invert = TRUE,value = TRUE)
[1] "multifarmacias" "multifarmacias"
```